# Difference between Controller and Dispatcher in MVC for web frameworks?

Tags: java, python, mvc

In MVC applied to WSGI or Java EE, is the Servlet a controller, dispatcher, or both? I think I've seen system diagrams where the controller and the dispatcher are different. Could the controller control SQL statements which should not be in the dispatcher?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Controller**
The controller is the initial contact point for handling all requests in the system. The controller may delegate to a helper to complete authentication and authorization of a user or to initiate contact retrieval.

**Dispatcher**
A dispatcher is responsible for view management and navigation, managing the choice of the next view to present to the user, and providing the mechanism for vectoring control to this resource.

A dispatcher can be encapsulated within a controller or can be a separate component working in coordination. The dispatcher provides either a static dispatching to the view or a more sophisticated dynamic dispatching mechanism.